# Next js api to return new document from mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, next.js, architecture

I have made the next js API that returns a document from Mongo db collection.

```
import acc from "@/models/acc";
import acc from "@/models/accc";

export default async (req, res) => {
    const conn = connectMongo();

    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        const facc = await acc.findOne({"Working":true, "InUse":false});
        if (facc) {
            facc.InUse = true;
            facc.LastUsed = new Date().getTime()
            await facc.save();
        }
        
        res.status(200).json({ facc});
```

But the API call gives the same document again and again.
I want to make the API behave like an iterator over the Mongo db collection i.e. it should return a new document every time I call it and once it is out of the documents it starts from the 0 position. is there a way to do so?